# How to apply specific colors to D3.js map based on data values?

Tags: d3.js

I have a US counties map that's supposed to show in animation the amount of water yield for counties in a 14-day period.  I need to show the colors in red (less than 50 mm), green(greater than 49 mm and lower than 100 mm), and blue (greater than 100 mm).  I've adapted from Mike Bostock and Rich Donohue the following codes:

```
<style>
.county {
    fill:steelblue;
    stroke: #fff; /*White*/
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

#play, #clock {
    position: absolute;
    /*top: 15px;*/
}

#play {
    /*left: 15px;*/
    left: 160px;
    top: 140px;
}

#clock {
    left: 220px;
    top: 148px;
}
```

```
<button id="play">Play</button>
<span id="clock">Day</span>
<h1 style="text-align:center">14-Day Water Yield By County</h1>

<div id="svgDiv1" style="text-align:center">
<svg width="960" height="600" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round">
    <defs>
        <filter id="blur">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

```
<script>

//globals
var width, height, projection, path, group, graticule, svg, defs, attributeArray = [], currentAttribute = 0, playing = false;

function init() {

    setMap();
    animateMap();

}

function setMap() {

    svg = d3.select("svg");

    defs = svg.select("defs");

    path = d3.geoPath();

    d3.json("/topo/us-10m.v1.json", function (error, us) {
        if (error) throw error;

        defs.append("path")
            .attr("id", "nation")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties)));

        svg.append("use")
            .attr("xlink:href", "#nation")
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0.2)
            .attr("filter", "url(#blur)");

        svg.append("use")
            .attr("xlink:href", "#nation")
            .attr("fill", "#fff");

        svg.append("path")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#777")
            .attr("stroke-width", 0.70)
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function (a, b) { return a !== b; })));
    });

    loadData();  // let's load our data next
}

function loadData() {
    queue()   // queue function loads all external data files asynchronously
      .defer(d3.json, "/topo/us-10m.v1.json")  // our geometries
      .defer(d3.csv, "/data/wtryld.csv")  // and associated data in csv file
      .await(processData);   // once all files are loaded, call the processData function passing the loaded objects as arguments
}

function processData(error, us, countyData) {
    // function accepts any errors from the queue function as first argument, then
    // each data object in the order of chained defer() methods above
    if (error) throw error;

    //Get values from geojson
    var conus = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties); // store the path in variable for ease

    //Get values from csv file
    for (var i in conus.features) {    // for each geometry object
        for (var j in countyData) {  // for each row in the CSV
            if (conus.features[i].id == countyData[j].id) {  // if they match
                for (var k in countyData[i]) {   // for each column in the a row within the CSV
                    if (k != 'id' && k != 'County') {  // select only number of days as column headings
                        if (attributeArray.indexOf(k) == -1) {
                            attributeArray.push(k);  // add new column headings to our array for later
                        }
                        conus.features[i].properties[k] = Number(countyData[j][k])  // add each CSV column key/value to geometry object
                    }
                }
                break;  // stop looking through the CSV since we made our match
            }
        }
    }
    d3.select('#clock').html(attributeArray[currentAttribute]);  // populate the clock initially with the current day
    drawMap(conus);  // let's mug the map now with our newly populated data object
}

//Sort function; can specify multiple columns to sort: propSort("STATE", "COUNTY");
function propSort(props) {
    if (!props instanceof Array) props = props.split(",");
    return function sort(a, b) {
        var p;
        a = a.properties;
        b = b.properties;
        for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
            p = props[i];
            if (typeof a[p] === "undefined") return -1;
            if (a[p] < b[p]) return -1;
            if (a[p] > b[p]) return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
}

function drawMap(conus) {

    svg.selectAll(".feature")   // select country objects (which don't exist yet)
      .data(conus.features)   // bind data to these non-existent objects
      .enter().append("path") // prepare data to be appended to paths
      .attr("class", "county") // give them a class for styling and access later
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d.properties.id; }, true)  // give each a unique id for access later
      .attr("d", path); // create them using the svg path generator defined above

    var dataRange = getDataRange(); // get the min/max values from the current day's range of data values
    d3.selectAll('.county')  // select all the counties
        .attr('fill-opacity', function (d) {
            return getColor(d.properties[attributeArray[currentAttribute]], dataRange);  // give them an opacity value based on their current value
        });
}

function sequenceMap() {
    var dataRange = getDataRange(); // get the min/max values from the current year's range of data values
    d3.selectAll('.county').transition()  //select all the counties and prepare for a transition to new values
      .duration(300)  // give it a smooth time period for the transition
      .attr('fill-opacity', function (d) {
          return getColor(d.properties[attributeArray[currentAttribute]], dataRange);  // the end color value
      })
}

function getColor(valueIn, valuesIn) {
    // create a linear scale
    var color = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([valuesIn[0], valuesIn[1]])  // input uses min and max values
      .range([.3, 1]);   // output for opacity between .3 and 1 %

    return color(valueIn);  // return that number to the caller
}

function getDataRange() {
    // function loops through all the data values from the current data attribute
    // and returns the min and max values

    var min = Infinity, max = -Infinity;
    d3.selectAll('.county')
        .each(function (d, i) {
          var currentValue = d.properties[attributeArray[currentAttribute]];
          if (currentValue <= min && currentValue != -99 && currentValue != 'undefined') {
              min = currentValue;
          }
          if (currentValue >= max && currentValue != -99 && currentValue != 'undefined') {
              max = currentValue;
          }
      });
    return [min, max];
}

function animateMap() {

    var timer;  // create timer object
    d3.select('#play')
      .on('click', function () {  // when user clicks the play button
          if (playing == false) {  // if the map is currently playing
              timer = setInterval(function () {   // set a JS interval
                  if (currentAttribute < attributeArray.length - 1) {
                      currentAttribute += 1;  // increment the current attribute counter
                  } else {
                      currentAttribute = 0;  // or reset it to zero
                  }
                  sequenceMap();  // update the representation of the map
                  d3.select('#clock').html(attributeArray[currentAttribute]);  // update the clock
              }, 2000);

              d3.select(this).html('Stop');  // change the button label to stop
              playing = true;   // change the status of the animation
          } else {    // else if is currently playing
              clearInterval(timer);   // stop the animation by clearing the interval
              d3.select(this).html('Play');   // change the button label to play
              playing = false;   // change the status again
          }
      });
}


window.onload = init();  // magic starts here
```

The above code applies "choropleth" color by using fill-opacity. Only steelblue color in differing shades.  But I need to apply green, blue and red colors.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than using css to set the color of all features and then applying an opacity value from your linear scale to each feature, you can output a color directly with your scale (D3 scale ranges accept colors). Then, instead of setting your fill-opacity, just set the fill.

For example:

```js
var color = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 9])  
  .range(["blue", "green"]); 
  
var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width',500)
    .attr('height',200);
    
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(d3.range(10))
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x',function(d,i) { return i * 40; })
    .attr('y',30)
    .attr('width',30)
    .attr('height',30)
    .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color(i); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Just be sure that your css doesn't still specify a steel blue color.

You can also use hex color codes or specify multiple steps:

```js
var color = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 5, 9])  
  .range(["blue", "yellow", "green"]); 
  
var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width',500)
    .attr('height',200);
    
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(d3.range(10))
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x',function(d,i) { return i * 40; })
    .attr('y',30)
    .attr('width',30)
    .attr('height',30)
    .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color(i); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Though, you may want a threshold scale if you want clear steps for each value:

```js
var color = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain([2, 5, 9])  
  .range(["blue","yellow","green","orange"]); 
  
var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width',500)
    .attr('height',200);
    
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(d3.range(10))
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x',function(d,i) { return i * 40; })
    .attr('y',30)
    .attr('width',30)
    .attr('height',30)
    .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color(i); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

There is one more element in the range than the domain for the threshold scale. Imagine a single threshold, it would have one value for more than, one value for less than.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Andrew.  I tried:

     var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 160, 325]  //these are min, avg, max values from csv file
    .range["red", "green", "blue"]);  //dry, medium, wet colors

I can't make it access the actual csv file to read the daily values and apply colors based on the values read.  Hence, it's not animating when button is clicked.  I wish I could attach my csv file but don't know how in this forum.

Comment: Need to clarify a few details. Was the original script successfully modifying the counties' transparency based on the csv values? Without any animation, are you able to color counties initially when drawing them?

Comment: Yes.  The original script does animation when the play button is clicked and the transparencies are okay.  Also, initial color is set to display the Day 1 data.  So original script is working.  But my bosses want colors, I think similar to a "heat map", where you can see the trend over time of which counties has dry/wet days, so farmers in those areas can decide whether to apply fertilizers or not and other practices they need to do.

Comment: To understand better: when you change the scale range here: `.range([.3, 1]); ` to be just two colors (for sake of testing), remove the css for the fill, and change all references of `fill-opacity` to `fill` in your example code, you get everything with a black fill? What happens in this case?

Comment: After replacing 'fill-opacity' with 'fill', everything is filled with black color.  Clicking the button seems to perform the animation since the day is cycling from day 1 to 14.  However, the fill portion is not coloring.  It's still all black.

Comment: Where you assign the fill (where your inline function is), what is being returned by the scale? Specifically, if you were to place `console.log(getColor(d.properties[attributeArray[currentAttribute]], dataRange)` before the return statement? If you paste the csv (or some rows of it) into a snippet in the question it might help.

Comment: Found a way for you to download my csv file.  Go to our website: https://nlet.brc.tamus.edu/ then hover over Downloads button and click "SWAT".  Select "Management" tab.  You can download "Water Yield csv file" by clicking it.  That's the csv file I used for this.

Comment: Adding console.log... before return statement:  it's supposed to return valuesIn[0], valuesIn[1].  But valuesIn[0] = NaN, while valuesIn[1] is a number, I assume the maximum value.

Comment: Will take a close look shortly, is this an accurate topojson to use: https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json ? (I can't find many matching ids in it though). And you appear to be using two version so of d3: `d3.scale.linear` is from v3 and `d3.geoPath` is from v4. `d3.scaleLinear` is the v4 equivalent.

Comment: Forgot to change my getColor function.  Changed the range to:
    .range(["red", "blue"]);

It's now animating and changing colors to red and blue.  But the valueIn variable in getColor function is "undefined". and it can't show three colors, so I only used red and blue.  Also, it seems to only animate a few counties; majority are still black-no animation.

Comment: The animation of a few counties is what I noticed in testing. That's why I was wondering about the matching ids, if you are joining your data by id, it doesn't seem that there are corresponding rows (or many of them) shared by the csv and the json.

Comment: I've tested the changes as far as colors go and it seems to work: https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/71d453f375dd177660d3b00cceb32687. However, I had to jerry rig the join - it's arbitrary. I used a script to assign new id values to the csv so that all counties would show and change. This is a different problem than the color, and one that is puzzling, it isn't clear where the id values come from for the csv. I couldn't find any matches for number and county that were meaningful online. In any event, I hope that the bl.ock helps you with the color problems (three colors used in it).

Comment: Oh, there are forty or so more counties in the json than the csv, so some might not update as I didn't create new rows in the csv to create a full test set.

Comment: Yes.  I just thought of the counties id problem last night.  The ids are unique values generated by our model; it is not the FIPS or county FIPS that are normally assigned.  I was going to test today to use the actual counties topojson file that I made and see if that would work.  I'll try to stick to d3.js version 4 also; the version 3 I used to create the gaussian blur effect on the nation; but that isn't critical to what I'm doing.  Thanks for helping me.  I'd like to acknowledge your help once the website is live.  How do I credit you?  Do you have a website I could create a link to?

Comment: Hi, I used the topojson file I created using ArcGIS and mapshaper tool and it's now working. I had to add a projection (geoAlbers()) in the setMap() function for my counties map to show.  I can't thank you enough.   I WILL add your name in our acknowledgment page once our website is live.  Again, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.