# Adding tooltips to d3.js map using csv file

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I would like to add tooltips for a project previously discussed here:

[How to apply specific colors to D3.js map based on data values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546344/how-to-apply-specific-colors-to-d3-js-map-based-on-data-values/42546557#42546557)

I've added a style for the tooltip-container as follows:

```
<style>
#tooltip-container{
      background: #eee;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
      color: #333;
      display: none;
      font-size: 12px;      
      padding: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      right: 200px;
      top: 300px;
      width: 140px;
      height: 230px;
      z-index: 10;
    }
</style>
```

I also added the html tooltip container in a div:

```
<div id="tooltip-container"></div>
```

I've revised my drawMap() function as follows:

```
function drawMap(conus) {
    svg.selectAll(".feature") 
      .data(conus.features)   
      .enter().append("path") 
      .attr("class", "county")
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d.properties.ID_1; }, true)  
      .attr("d", path) 
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          $("#tooltip-container").show();
      })
      .on("mouseout", function () {
          $("#tooltip-container").hide();
      });

    //Fill county colors
    var dataRange = getDataRange(); 

    d3.selectAll('.county')
        .attr('fill', function (d) {
            return getColor(d.properties[attributeArray[currentAttribute]], dataRange);
        });
}
```

What I need to do now are as follows:

When a user clicks the STOP button, the tooltip-container should display the appropriate warning text for that day from the "warnings.csv" file.  The csv file can be downloaded from here:  https://nlet.brc.tamus.edu/Home/Swat) by selecting the Management tab in the SWAT download section and selecting the "Warnings csv file".

Then, as users hover over the map, the tooltip-container should switch to that county and display the appropriate warning for the county for that day.

Appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't read csv file:

.on("mouseover", function (d) {
              $("#tooltip-container").show();
              var html = "";

              html += "<table><tr><strong>" + d.properties.County + "</strong></tr><br/><br/>" +
                      "<tr>ID:  " + d.properties.ID_1 + "</tr></table>";

              d3.csv("/data/warnings.csv", function (d,i) {
                  return {
                      County: d.County,
                      id: d.id,
                      warn: d[i]
                  };
              });

              tooltip.html(html);
          })

Comment: Able to read csv file but it won't display. I sorted my csv file by id:

var mywarning = loadWarning(d.properties.ID_1, day);

function loadWarning(id, day)
    {
        var warning = "";

        d3.csv("/data/warnings2.csv", function (error, data) {  
            for (var i in data) {
                if (data[i].id == id) {
                    warning = data[i][day];
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        return warning;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...solved this.  I revised the following functions from this project:

```
<div id="tooltip-container"></div>
function drawMap(conus) {
    var curr = $("#clock")[0].innerText;
    var day = curr.charAt(0);

    svg.selectAll(".feature")   // select country objects (which don't exist yet)
      .data(conus.features)   // bind data to these non-existent objects
      .enter().append("path") // prepare data to be appended to paths
      .attr("class", "county") // give them a class for styling and access later
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d.properties.ID_1; }, true)  // give each a unique id for access later
      .attr("d", path) // create them using the svg path generator defined above
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          $("#tooltip-container").show();
          loadWarning(d, day);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function (d) {
          $("#tooltip-container").hide();
      });

    var dataRange = getDataRange(); // get the min/max values from the current day's range of data values

    d3.selectAll('.county')
        .attr('fill', function (d) {
            return getColor(d.properties[attributeArray[currentAttribute]], dataRange);
        });
}

function loadWarning(d, day)
{
    var html = "";
    var tooltip = d3.select("#tooltip-container");

    d3.csv("/data/warnings2.csv", function (error, data) {  
        for (var i in data) {
            if (data[i].id == d.properties.ID_1) {
                html += "<table><tr><strong>" + d.properties.County + "</strong></tr><br/>" +
                 "<tr>ID:  " + d.properties.ID_1 + "</tr><br/><br/>" +
                 "<tr><div style='text-align:left'>" + data[i][day] + "</div></tr></table>";

                tooltip.html(html);
            }
        }            
    });
}
```